# What's wrong with the height of the tree of my implementation?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was doing some exercise on

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/height-of-binary-tree/1

Here is the input format that has been used.
[image]

I see that their implementation has number of nodes traversed and not number of edges.
So, I have added 1 to my answer to compensate for that. However, my answer is failing for their input
"5 5 N 4 10 N 8 5 N 8 8 N 6", which I don't understand how it can fail. I am having low confidence and want to know if
I am doing anything wrong to find out the height of the tree here.

```
int result1 = 0;
int result2 = 0;
int MyHeight(Node *root)
{
   if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
   {
       return 0;
   }

   if(root->left)
   {
     //cout<<"Executing root->left = data = "<<root->data<<endl;
     result1 =  MyHeight(root->left) + 1;
     //cout<<"height -left --of .."<<root->data<<" = "<<result1<<endl;
   }
   if(root->right)
   {
     result2 = MyHeight(root->right) + 1;
     //cout<<"right.height of .."<<root->data<<" = "<<result2<<endl;
   }
   if(result1 > result2)
       return result1;
   return result2;
}

int get_Height(Node* root)
{
  // Your code here
  //cout<<"root->data"<<root->data;
  return MyHeight(root);   
}
```

On what scenario, this implementation can fail?
Can you draw a tree in the scenario where it will fail?
I have debug it and I can't see what is going wrong there.
It sounds like an invalid  BST they have but I want to know if my implementation is correct or not. I cannot see that it is wrong actually.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages, only the language you're actually writing in.

Comment: What does "5 5 N 4 10 N 8 5 N 8 8 N 6" mean? The complete problem statement needs to be in the question. Not just a link to an external site - especially one that requires log in.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to *debug* your program? For example by drawing up the tree on paper, with squares for nodes and arrows for pointers, and then step through the code in a debugger and do the same modifications you do in the program in the paper (erasing and redrawing arrows or even boxes as needed)? Can help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Actually, using pen and paper *before* you write code is also very helpful to write code that doesn't have errors (or at least fewer errors). And don't write large pieces of code without testing, write only a few lines at a time, building (with extra warnings enable, and that you treat as errors that must be fixed) and then testing. Once the few lines builds and works fine, you write the next few lines.

Comment: Recursion and global variables don't mix well. Learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would be far more useful than geeksforgeeks could ever be.

Comment: There is no reason for `result1` and `result2` to be global – you need them to have the same values after recursing as they did before, but they won't. Make them local.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion and global variables don't mix well. You keep overriding these globals in each recursive call.

Specifically `result2 = MyHeight(root->right) + 1;` can override `result1`, such that it is not height of `root->left` anymore, but the height of `root->right->left`. Explaining recursion is quite tricky, better get your debugger out, step through your code and watch how `result1` and `result2` change.

Global variables should always be used with care and in this case there is no reason to use global variables at all, making `result1` and `result2` local to `MyHeight` should fix your problem.